# substring before last space xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a name field of length 30 as below:

```
<Name>Rainbow Charity             </Name>
<Name>Ben Tromy Jig               </Name>
```

I need to substring before the last space. So I need the below using xslt:

```
<Name>Rainbow Charity</Name>
<Name>Ben Tromy Jig</Name>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `normalize-space()` work for you?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Not, if the intermediate groups of spaces have length > 1 and if they need to be preserved

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev The question is addressed to the OP.

Comment: Please specify what XSLT version you are using. In 2.0 this is easily done using the replace() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @michael.hor257k

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Name/text()">
    <xsl:sequence select="normalize-space(.)" />
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With input

```xml
<example>
  <Name>Rainbow Charity             </Name>
  <Name>Ben Tromy Jig               </Name>
</example>
```

produces

```xml
<example>
  <Name>Rainbow Charity</Name>
  <Name>Ben Tromy Jig</Name>
</example>
```

Answer (score 2):

**I. Here is a pure XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Name/text()" name="trimRight">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
    
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(substring($pText, string-length($pText)) = ' ')">
          <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:call-template name="trimRight">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" 
                 select="substring($pText, 1, string-length($pText) -1)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the below XML document** (derived from the OP-provided one, but with varying number of spaces in the intermediate whitespace segments):

```
<t>
    <Name>Rainbow   Charity             </Name>
    <Name>Ben  Tromy Jig               </Name>
</t>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <Name>Rainbow   Charity</Name>
   <Name>Ben  Tromy Jig</Name>
</t>
```

**Do note**: Unlike using `normalize-space()` which removes all spaces but one from any longest contiguous substring containing only whitespace, this solution preserves all intermediate segments of spaces.

---

**II. An XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Name/text()">
     <xsl:sequence select="replace(., '\s+$', '')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <Name>Rainbow   Charity</Name>
   <Name>Ben  Tromy Jig</Name>
</t>
```

Comment: That is nice, @dimitre-novatchev, re-using the template for both matching via apply-templates and calling via call-template.